# Which is a better electrolyte for electroplating copper?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, electrolysis

I need to know which is a better electrolyte to use when electroplating copper: copper sulfate or copper nitrate?

Comment: Better in what way? Copper sulfate is readily available on that well known auction site (e***) and it is very inexpensive. Copper nitrate is not so easily available because it can easily be used to make other nitrates. And nitrates are more troublesome (electroactive) than sulfates when it comes to electrochemistry.

Comment: What i was wondering is whether one of them helps influence the mass transfer between electrodes. So basically is the total mass of both electrodes added together closer to the starting mass depending on which electrolyte I use or do they both have the same outcome.@EdV

Comment: Just a guess, but I think it is about the same. Nothing more I can say, frankly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to price advantage, CuSO4 also provides a source of sulfate ions, which are relatively stable. The sulfate anion is also a known scavenger of radicals that may be present in the solution. For example, a reaction between sulfate and the hydroxyl radical (a possible electrolysis product):

$\ce{SO4^{2-} + .OH -> .SO4^- + OH^-}$

And, the creation of Cupric sulfate with the action of the sulfate radical anion acting on cuprous:

$\ce{.SO4^- + Cu^{+} -> CuSO4}$

Related reactions starting with chloride:

$\ce{Cl- + .OH -> .Cl + OH^-}$

$\ce{.Cl + .Cl -> Cl2 }$

$\ce{Cl2 + H2O -> H+ + Cl- + HOCl}$

where the hypochlorous acid is a precursor to the creation of [copper oxychloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicopper_chloride_trihydroxide), an insoluble basic chloride, to be avoided.

With nitrate anion, the essential potential problem is that with associated radical presence (per the ongoing electrolysis), in time, NO3- can be broken down to NO2-,..., even NH3, so probably avoid also.

In the presence of further created active radicals, I suspect, a possible attack of the newly plated Copper, so I will not be surprised if you witness some variation in the quality of results by switching between salts.

More research may be valuable, here is [a video](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+plate+metal+with+copper&rlz=1CAHKDC_enUS750US750&oq=how+to+plate+metal+with+copper+&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.23621j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_mqCCXsW2DdC3ggfs9KeQDw59) that uses CuSO4 also.

My recommended answer is CuSO4.